# Range of address in 16 bit microprocessor

Tags: microprocessors

My book mentions that when the intel processors were 16 bit the maximum memory range it could access was 64KB.

How many registers were there in such processors . When each register is 16 bit , the number of combinations of 1 and 0 it can hold is (2) ^ (16). Hence the memory range is (2) ^ 16 bits = (2) ^ 13 bytes = 8192 bytes ,approximately 8 kilobytes . So what kind of arrangement resulted in 64 KB of memory range ?

Can it be because to get an address we add a base to an offset . The first value can possibly hold 2^16 bits which is approximately 8KB and so being the possibility of values for the other value ,the total number of address = 8x8 = 64Kb ?

Comment: Each memory address corresponds to one *byte*, not one *bit*.

Comment: Each address refers to a byte of memory, so the memory range is 2^16 which is 64KB. Modern processors are not bit-addressable.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpnE6UAfbtU this series is extremely helpful in understanding processors (at least it was for me). Skip to ~5 minutes for explanation of 8 bit registers.

Comment: The real world is a little more complicated - the 8086 had 16 bit address registers but a 20 bit address bus.

Comment: @HenkHolterman : So how does the 20 address bus result in 64 KB ?

Comment: @NetMage : How is 2^16 = 64KB ?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog : So address range = no of bytes possible = 2^8 bytes = 256 bytes..right ?

Comment: How did you arrive at `2^8`? You seem to be getting very confused

Comment: @meowgoesthedog : sorry it should be 2^13 bytes ..my bad

Comment: No, you don't seem to have understood mine or any of the others' comments. Each possible value of memory address refers to one *byte*, so the maximum number of bytes is `2^16`. Counting the number of *bits* is wrong.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog : Ok so when they  say 16 bit it means 16 bytes ?

Comment: No, no. 16 is the width of the address bus (the number of wires), and therefore the length of the address register. A 16 bit integer can have up to 2^16 = 65536 values, each of which corresponds to a memory location one byte in size.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog : Ok ..now i got it ..thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The processors are not bit-addressable. The smallest unit of memory that can be named with an address is a byte. See [Byte Addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_addressing).

Architectures supporting bit addressing are fairly rare. Back in the days of 36-bit machines and such, there was often a different pointer format that allowed addressing variable sized "bytes." (Once upon a time, we didn't even have widespread agreement on whether bytes should be 6, 7, 8, 9, or more bits. There really were machines with 36-bit, 72-bit, and even 47-bit registers. In order to more efficiently support different sized bytes architectures added pointer formats where part of the pointer was a word address and part specified the starting bit position and size of the bitfield. E.g. the PDP-10 was a 36-bit architecture with 18-bit addresses so this pointer format used half of a register for the address and half for the bitfield part.)

Word addressed machines are somewhat more common, especially in specialized applications. These allow addressing more bytes of memory than the bit-size of the address implies, but require shifting and masking to extract bytes and the pointer itself cannot specify which byte of a word it points to. As such one usually sees byte-adressable machines where the smallest size load and store are for (e.g. 64-bit) words, not bytes, rather than true word-addressed machines.

Comment: Zalman stern : Could you elaborate a bit more about how it makes 64kb ?

Comment: A 16-bit register has 2^16 unique values. That is 64 kilo values, assuming "kilo" means "1024" as is typical in this context. Each of those values names a single byte. Thus the entire addressable range is 64 kilobytes. (One can argue about whether "kb" or "kB" or etc. means kilobytes or kilobits. And people get into the difference between 1,000 and 1,024 via "kibi" instead of "kilo", etc. None of that seems material to the question.)

Comment: What used to be one of my favorite processors shows the complications possible when optimizing for a particular use case: the [HP Saturn CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Saturn) for HP 41 calculators.